# electron & react: No resource with given URL found, DevTools failed to load SourceMap

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, react-scripts

For production (mac dmg) builds of my electron app, I am unable to trigger `location.reload()`, connect to `redux-dev-tools`, and the sourcemap fails to load.

When the app is loaded, the console warns that it cannot load the sourcemap:
[image: Screen Shot 2021-05-04 at 3 56 09 PM]

The `index.html` in the sources says the resource cannot be loaded:
[image: Screen Shot 2021-05-04 at 3 56 57 PM]

Executing `location.reload()` causes the app to crash with a white screen and no console logs (this command works in electron dev builds).

My electron code is contained in `electron/index.electron.js` and the relevant snippets are:

```js
const options = {
    icon: join(__dirname, '../src/common/assets/app-icons/png/256x256.png'),
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        preload: join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
};
// ...
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  ...options,
  ...windowOptions
});
// ...    
const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
    pathname: "file://../build/index.html"
});
// ...
mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
```

The relevant `package.json` snippets:

```json
"homepage": "./",
"scripts": {
  "electron-build:mac": "rm -rf dist/ && yarn build && electron-builder -m",
},
"build": {
    "appId": "appId",
    "extends": null,
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "src/common/assets/**/*",
      "public/*",
      "electron/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "./src/common/assets"
    }
  },
"devDependencies": {
  "electron": "^11.3.0",
  "electron-builder": "^22.9.1"
```

The only thing I can confirm in dev is that running `location.reload()` successfully reloads the app.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide a recurrence of the demo (github repo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your url is not valid,
you should change this:

```
const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
    pathname: "file://../build/index.html"
});
```

to this

```
const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
    pathname: "file://${ __dirname}/build/index.html"
});
```